# Firefox-Extension: Catching "onInstalled" event

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am porting my extension from Chrome to Firefox using WebExtensions.

There is no support for the "browser.runtime.onInstalled"-event so is there really no way to catch this event?

Comment: I guess I should just use a localStorage-variable to run a script once after installing and then never again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use local storage. On uninstall the storage is cleared. On disable the storage is not cleared.

```
browser.storage.get('local', 'install_date').then(function(install_date) {
    if (!install_date) {
        // just installed
        browser.storage.set('local', {
            install_date: Date.now()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I already solved this via localStorage.setItem() but I have the problem that the user can delete this data when he clears his cookies.

This is not the case with chrome so is it because I use "Nightly", a FireFox developer version or because I use the localStorage-method which ist wrong for my purpose?

Or is it not possible with FireFox to store data permanently without user permission to delete (except from uninstall)?

Comment: Using `chrome.stroage` will fix this problem @JuliusS. localStorage will always get cleared when user clears cookies/data. Firefox people did it right.

Comment: Yes I already started to change everything to this method and everything works as intended. It is very annoying that different browsers handle it differently but I will adapt my chrome code, too, just in case they will change the user permissions in future.

Comment: I forgot: I use the callback function of the `chrome.storage` methods. Does it make any difference compared to using `.then()` ?

Comment: There shouldn't any issue between using callback form or the promise form. If there is a difference then it's a bug.